# Как обратиться к IWebDriver из другого класса?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

В одном классе объявлен WebDriver

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Potok()
    {    
        IWebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
    }
}
```

Как из другого класса обратиться к wd.Manage() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если клас статический то:

```
StaticClassName.wd.Manage();
```

если класс динамический:

```
var a = new DinamicClassName();
a.wd.Manage();
```

Comment: Подправил вопрос
IWebDriver объявлен внутри статического метода void Potok()

Comment: обьяви глобальную переменную в классе и в нее присваивай драйвер. А дальше по моему ответу.